# Docker login x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: linux, docker, ssl, ssl-certificate, redhat

I am running docker registry as container in Redhat Linux 7.5 with Docker 18.09.3-3 version. if configured with self-sign certificate.

container started successfully. it works with curl with-out any error. but giving error for `docker login` command.

**curl command works**

```
curl --cacert /etc/docker/certs.d/dockerhost\:5000/ca.crt https://dockerhost:5000 -v
```

**login command**

```
docker  login dockerhost:5000 
Error response from daemon: Get https://dockerhost:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

how to resolve this error message?

Thanks

Comment: Do check this link for solution. 
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-private-registry-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority/21262

Comment: tried those steps, before posting. I resovled it. my hostname set uppercase, cert cname was in lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hostname set with upper case letter. Certificate was generated with lower case name. I changed hostname to lowercase, it started working.